# Tableview not reloading after button click

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, ios8

I am working in swift. I have a protocol defined that has a function called reload. I have a home class which is a tableviewcontroller where I extend the protocol and implement the reload function. I have another class where there is a button. On this click of the button I set the delegate and the reload function is called. Until this step it works fine. Now in the reload function i want to refresh the home page, so i tried

```
tableview.reload()
```

this is not working and the app is crashing, then i tried calling

```
viewDidLoad()
```

this is also not refreshing the page. I dont want to use NSNotification

what am i doing wrong?
Can anybody please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: viewDidLoad is called by the OS. You must not call it. Try `view.needsDisplay = true`. Please show some excerpts from your protocol and the reload method.

Comment: What is the crash message?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your UITableView data source delegate methods are working properly?   You should look up viewDidLoad() and viewWillLoad(), etc... in the UIViewController reference page (Apple doc).  If you're serious about app development I recommend at the very least making the time to spend 15 - 30 minutes each looking at the UIViewController and UIView pages to familiarize yourself with them, since you'll be using them all the time. You should know basically how they work.  Also check out CALayers in UIViews.  Then you'll be better established to write really nice apps.

Answer (score 0):

you are setting a delegate on button touchup inside event, please check whether you are setting a delegate to your Home class .

Answer (score 0):

I assume your mean `tableview.reloadData()` which is the correct method to call for reloading your tableview.

You shall not call `viewDidLoad` by yourself.